# Closed paths/shapes in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to create a closed path in draw.io?

I would like to close a path to make an irregular shape that can then be given a fill colour? I can make a shape using a line and adding waypoints but I can't see how to join the endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot interactively draw a closed shape. If you want to create a shape that responds to the application's fill command, you'll need to create your own shape using the built-in [XML shape definition language](https://support.draw.io/display/DO/Editing+Shapes).

Comment: Thanks @David! That's such a shame, as otherwise draw.io is brilliant. Creating shapes in XML is not very efficient. I wonder if you can add waypoints to shapes, that would enable a rectangle to be turned into any shape. I can't see this in the XSD. Is this a vain hope?